# Django 1.9 AJAX form CSRF token 403 error - "CSRF cookie not set"

Tags: ajax, django, cookies, csrf, fetch-api

I've seen a lot about this on SO, but nothing can fix my problem.

**Problem:**

With CSRF middleware enabled, Django responds with 403 on AJAX form request, stating:

> "CSRF cookie not set."

Following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax), a JS functionality was implemented, that sets custom **"X-CSRFToken"** header.

It works as expected, gets **"csrftoken"** cookie from browser and posts it along with AJAX request:

```
x-csrftoken: 1a0u7GCQG0wepZHQNThIXeYpMy2lZOf2
```

But response is still 403.

**Tried solutions:**

I've tried everything I could find on SO or web, specifically:

- Checking that middleware is enabled:

  ```
  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
      ...
      'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
      ...
  ]
  ```
- Different browsers with cookies enabled;
- Decorating my view with `@ensure_csrf_cookie`;
- Setting `{% csrf_token %}` in my template;
- Using `render` shortcut which takes right request context;
- Setting custom `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME` and `CSRF_HEADER_NAME` in my `settings.py`;
- Explicitly setting `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False` and `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False`;
- Explicitly setting `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` setting;
- Testing on development and production server;
- Even `request.META["CSRF_COOKIE_USED"] = True` in my view, as someone suggested.

And still got nothing.

**Headers:**

If I use `@csrf_exempt` and `print(request.META)` in my view, it's clear that custom header **"X-CSRFToken"** is present in request and formatted according to Django documentation, with "HTTP_" prefix, replaced hyphens with underscores, all uppercase: **"HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN"**.

Even more, it's value matches with cookie set by Django.

**Cookies:**

Strange thing is, if I try to `print(request.COOKIES)` in my view, on page  and form load I can see **"csrftoken"** cookie there, but dictionary is **empty on AJAX request**. Can it be the problem?

Desperate to find what is actually wrong. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Can you show your actual view and javascript?

Comment: What you are using to send AJAX request? jQuery?

Comment: @Smile0ff: Fetch API.

Comment: Lol, it was a bit uncanny reading your debugging process because I followed those exact same steps in basically that exact same order :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, the issue is quite simple then:

Fetch API is not sending credentials by default. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials):

> The credentials read-only property of the Request interface indicates
>   whether the user agent should send cookies from the other domain in
>   the case of cross-origin requests. This is similar to XHR’s
>   withCredentials flag, but with three available values.

Default is `omit`, and it never sends cookies. You just need to add `same-origin` to your `fetch()` function arguments:

```
fetch(formUrl, {
    ...
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    ...
})
```

And you'll be good to go : )