# Django Rest Framework, CSRF and Vue.js

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vue.js

I'm trying to use Vue.js to do some POST methods to my REST Api that I created with Django Rest Framework. Problem is, I'm getting the `CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.` error when I post. But I can see the csrf cookie, and it's being added to the headers.

Here's my settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
    )
}
```

Here's my Vue.js config:

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
Vue.http.headers.common['HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'] = csrftoken;
```

And here's the relevant part of the headers that were sent:

```
Cookie:djdt=hide; tabstyle=raw-tab; sessionid=1gl533mrneudxw3l9l2vg0ja1yowwmeo; csrftoken=dN85bhztB1oVRov87BsUrWTM29Ff9sjn
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN:dN85bhztB1oVRov87BsUrWTM29Ff9sjn
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8000
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/agencies/6/add-profiles/
```

As you can see, Cookie.csrf and the HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN header match

I'm really stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: What `CSRF_HEADER_NAME` setting you use? I know that `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN` should be `X-CSRFTOKEN` when you send it, because django conventionally formats it within it's guts: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#csrf-header-name

Comment: do you have your apps in the same domain? or are you using CORS?

Comment: Yerko Palma is right, it could also be an issue with same-origin request policy or `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` setting.

Comment: Kid Binary, you were right. It was the `X-CSRFTOKEN' name

Comment: as a related question, was the [vue-resources](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) library required in order to set the header using the line of code: `Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRFTOKEN']`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I'm posting this as an answer to close the question.

The issue was because of the wrong CSRF header name that was sent on request. According to documentation:

> As with other HTTP headers in request.META, the header name received
>   from the server is normalized by converting all characters to
>   uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores, and adding an
>   'HTTP_' prefix to the name. For example, if your client sends a
>   'X-XSRF-TOKEN' header, the setting should be 'HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN'.

Also I'm leaving here a reference to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868312/django-1-9-ajax-form-csrf-token-403-error-csrf-cookie-not-set), which accumulates several problems that may lead to `CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.` error in Django.

Comment: For anyone using NGINX in their stack:  
If you leave the setting on default NGINX will not pass your header on.  
You can circumvent that by sending the header with hyphens instead of underscores and omit the HTTP_ part.Django will then restore that to the correct format.  

Below code should work for a standard Django set-up  

`var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRFTOKEN'] = csrftoken;`

Answer (score 2):

Get token from cookie:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

var csrftoken = readCookie('csrftoken');
```

Send token in headers POST:

```
  this.$http.post('http://'+document.location.host+'/api//',{params: {foo: 'bar'}}, {headers: {"X-CSRFToken":csrftoken }}).then(function (response) {
            this.response = response.data;
        },
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```